# Making partial payment for Magento2

Tags: magento2, order-state

i'm trying to add partial payment for magento 2, any suggestion in modifying the order state, or maybe a good tutorial on making module that integrate with the admin sections, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a payment module in magento 2 you can start by [magento sample payment gateway module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway). Make you customizations in it.

If you want to change the order status after payment processing you can use my function to change the statuses:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel,      
    array $data = []
) {
    ...
    $this->orderModel = $orderModel;

}
public function changeOrderStatus(){
    //it is used when payment fails.
    $orderId = 100 // get increment Id of order that you want
    $orderModel = $this->orderModel->loadByIncrementId($orderId);;
    $orderModel->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW, true); //STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT
    $orderModel->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW); //STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT
    $orderModel->addStatusToHistory($orderModel->getStatus(), 'Order processed successfully with reference');
    $orderModel->save();
}
```

Here are the list of the order states and statuses from magento core file. You can use these instead of `STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW`:

```
/**
 * Order states
 */
const STATE_NEW = 'new';

const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';

const STATE_PROCESSING = 'processing';

const STATE_COMPLETE = 'complete';

const STATE_CLOSED = 'closed';

const STATE_CANCELED = 'canceled';

const STATE_HOLDED = 'holded';

const STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW = 'payment_review';

/**
 * Order statuses
 */
const STATUS_FRAUD = 'fraud';

/**
 * Order flags
 */
const ACTION_FLAG_CANCEL = 'cancel';

const ACTION_FLAG_HOLD = 'hold';

const ACTION_FLAG_UNHOLD = 'unhold';

const ACTION_FLAG_EDIT = 'edit';

const ACTION_FLAG_CREDITMEMO = 'creditmemo';

const ACTION_FLAG_INVOICE = 'invoice';

const ACTION_FLAG_REORDER = 'reorder';

const ACTION_FLAG_SHIP = 'ship';

const ACTION_FLAG_COMMENT = 'comment';

/**
 * Report date types
 */
const REPORT_DATE_TYPE_CREATED = 'created';

const REPORT_DATE_TYPE_UPDATED = 'updated';
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify or change the order status you will need to use the **OrderRepositoryInterface** as since **load() and save()** are deprecated now.

```
...
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

class YourClassName{
    ...
    protected $_orderRepository;
    ...
    public function __construct(..., OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, ...){

        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        ...
    }
    ...
    public function setOrderStatus($orderID, $statusCode){
        try{
            // obtain the order with the order ID
            $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderID);
            $order->setState($statusCode)->setStatus($statusCode);
            $this->_orderRepository->save($order);
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            // add some logging here
            return false;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Call the function **setOrderStatus** with your custom status code like **partially paid orders**. You can use ready-made [Magento2 Partial Payment Extension By Milople](https://www.milople.com/magento-2-extensions/partial-payment-m2.html).